# Cut off geom_vline at geom_density height

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to highlight a specific point in a distribution. I am using `geom_vline` which works fine *except* that it extends beyond the curve drawn by `geom_density`. Is there any way to cut that vertical line off a the point it meets the curve drawn by `geom_density`?

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)

javelin <- mtcars[mtcars$car == "AMC Javelin", ]

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_density(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_vline(data = javelin, aes(xintercept = mpg))
```

[image]

Comment: I think ```annotate("segment", x = ?, xend = ?, y = 0, yend = 0.06)``` would work in your example (filling in the questionmarks ofcourse). But it will be a hassle if you have to manually fill it in for every graph you make.

Comment: yeah exactly. this is a reprex here but I am looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `geom_vline` here. You'll have to calculate the correct point and use `geom_segment`, but this really isn't that complex:

```r
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_density(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_segment(data = as.data.frame(density(mtcars$mpg)[1:2]) %>%
                      filter(seq(nrow(.)) == which.min(abs(x - javelin$mpg))),
               aes(x, 0, xend = x, yend = y))
```

[image]

If you want this to be easily generalised, you can define a little helper function:

```r
geom_vdensity <- function(data, at, ...) {
  ggplot2::geom_segment(
    data = dplyr::filter(as.data.frame(density(data)[1:2]),
                         seq_along(x) == which.min(abs(x - at))),
    ggplot2::aes(x, 0, xend = x, yend = y), ...)
}
```

This allows:

```r
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_density(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_vdensity(data = mtcars$mpg, at = javelin$mpg, color = "red")
```

[image]

and

```r
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_density(aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_vdensity(data = iris$Petal.Length, at = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is great. I modified the answer a little to accept groups: `library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)

 
min_df <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  group_modify(~as_tibble(density(.x$mpg)[1:2])) %>% 
  left_join(mtcars %>% 
              group_by(cyl) %>% 
              summarise(min_val = min(mpg)), by = "cyl") %>% 
  slice(which.min(abs(x-min_val))) 

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_density(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_segment(data = min_df, aes(x, 0, xend = x, yend = y), colour = "red") +
  facet_wrap(vars(cyl)) 
`

Comment: @boshek you're welcome. Worth wrapping it in a function if you're going to use it on other data sets.